I installed the simple_kafka_client for my symfony project and getting conflict errors
This is the relevant GitHub repo.
I am trying to use this code:


use PyaeSoneAung\AwsMskIamSaslSigner\AwsMskIamSaslSigner;
use SimpleKafkaClient\Configuration;
use SimpleKafkaClient\Producer;

$conf = new Configuration();
$conf->set('metadata.broker.list', 'kafka:9092');
$conf->set('security.protocol', 'SASL_SSL');
$conf->set('sasl.mechanisms', 'OAUTHBEARER');

$producer = new Producer($conf);

$awsMskIamSaslSigner = new AwsMskIamSaslSigner(
    'us-east-1',
    'testAccessKeyId',
    'testSecretAccessKey'
);
$token = $awsMskIamSaslSigner->generateToken();
$producer->setOAuthBearerToken($token['token'], $token['expiryTime'], 'principalClaimName=azp');

$topic = $producer->getTopicHandle('topic-name');

$topic->producev(
    RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA,
    RD_KAFKA_MSG_F_BLOCK,
    'value',
    'key',
    ['header-key' => 'header-value']
);

$producer->poll(0);

$result = $producer->flush(20000);



but I am getting this error:

Attempted to load class "Configuration" from namespace "SimpleKafkaClient".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Mockery\Configuration", "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\DeprecationErrorHandler\Configuration", "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "ProxyManager\Configuration", "PDepend\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "PDepend\Util\Configuration", "OpenTelemetry\Symfony\OtelBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "OpenTelemetry\Symfony\OtelSdkBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "OpenTelemetry\SDK\Common\Configuration\Configuration", "Jose\Bundle\JoseFramework\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Doctrine\ORM\Configuration", "Doctrine\Migrations\Configuration\Configuration", "Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration", "Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "DDTrace\Configuration", "Aws\Retry\Configuration", "Aws\Sts\RegionalEndpoints\Configuration", "Aws\EndpointDiscovery\Configuration", "Aws\ClientSideMonitoring\Configuration", "Aws\DefaultsMode\Configuration", "Aws\Endpoint\UseDualstackEndpoint\Configuration", "Aws\Endpoint\UseFipsEndpoint\Configuration", "Aws\S3\RegionalEndpoint\Configuration" or "Aws\S3\UseArnRegion\Configuration"?


Sounds like the class Configuration does not exist - how did you install that Kafka extension? Also, are you sure this problem is in any way related to AWS or Doctrine?

Hi, thanks for your reply. I followed the below steps.
Step1: By using this repo https://php-kafka.github.io/php-simple-kafka-client.github.io/installation/ i have created the simple_kafka_client.so and put it in this path php/conf.d
Step2: I have installed the Kafka library in my application by using this command: composer require php-kafka/php-simple-kafka-lib
Step3: I added the below code something like in my Symfony project and tried to execute
use SimpleKafkaClient\Configuration;
use SimpleKafkaClient\Producer;
$conf = new Configuration();

Did you also check whether the extension got enabled properly? Just putting it into any folder usually isn't enough, you need to add it to your php.ini

When i try to run this command php -m i could able to see in the list "simple_kafka_client" Like below. Still we need to keep in php.ini file?
pgsql
Phar
posix
pspell
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
simple_kafka_client
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tid

Keep in mind that all clarification should be added to the question, not to the comment section. Also, if php -m already lists the extension, that is a good sign - but do you also call your script on the shell, or through any webserver that might use a different PHP configuration?
